# How to forecast hierarchical time series with external unique external regressors for each base time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have hierarchical time series with 70 base time series, forming 4 level of hierarchies. I am using `forecast()` function in R from the package forecast.

The documentation reads:

`When xreg and newxreg are passed, the same covariates are applied to every series in the hierarchy.`

Is it possible to tweak, in such a way that correct regressors are used for individual time series?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Create your own forecasts using any method you like, then use `combinef()` to reconcile them.